# Can I use a twisted pair cable to send power to a device that uses a micro-USB jack?

Tags: power-supply, usb-device

I purchased a Google Home Mini that according to the specs this requires 5V, 1.8A.  The OEM power cable has a transformer that plugs into AC and has about 3 feet of cable terminating at a USB micro plug.

I have in my wall a cable (about 10 feet) with 2 twisted pairs and the gauge is 22. I want to use this to act as an extension to power the Google Home mini.  I would snip off the wire connected to the micro USB cable and solder the wires to the cable in the wall, and then solder the wires at the other end and then plug into an outlet.

Will this work, and is it safe?

ETA:  The cable in the wall was originally for a motion sensor.

Comment: YOu can buy extension cords... https://www.amazon.ca/DANTENG-Premium-Braided-Android-Samsung/dp/B074YJ64NN/ref=sr_1_19_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1511571539&sr=8-19-spons&keywords=micro+usb+extension&psc=1

Comment: As for whether Google Home Mini is safe, that is a whole other subject.

Comment: What was the twisted pair used for? Phone? Ethernet? There are use over Ethernet adapters you can buy for cheap. No need to splice cables.

Comment: I *could* try an extension cord, but the cable is in the wall already and I’d most likely have to cut drywall.  I’d prefer to avoid that if possible.  I suppose I could use the existing cable and try to use that to pull the extension through, but who knows how it is wired in the wall.  It could be looped around god knows what.

Comment: This is actually *not* likely to work reliably - the device in question has not only a wifi radio, but a speaker, and so can have fairly high peak power demand.  The proposed cable will probably have too much voltage drop under load, and it's quite likely that the device will brown out and reboot when it hits a loud spot in music playback.

Comment: I'm starting to get confused about what you have here... Why would you have to cut into the wall? You might need to draw a sketch of what you have in mind or take some pictures.

Comment: @trevor he's reusing security/alarm/doorbell cable.

Comment: @Passerby ya I see the edit now.

Comment: It will probably work reasonably well until/unless your solder joints fail. Don't be tempted to leave out the data wires. The "transformer" probably uses them to signal to the device what it is. (probably D+ and D- are shorted together on the transformer side).

Comment: You might be able to use the old cable as a draw wire to pull a more suitable cable through.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can use 22 awg cable to carry a few (7) amps. With two conductors, you doible the area, halve the resistance, hence halve the voltage drop and any power loss. Essentially like a single 19 awg cable. For 5V 2 Amps over 20 feet (round trip), you don't have much to worry about.

Except building and electrical code.

Comment: How can I use a MM to test this before snipping and soldering?

Comment: You could use a continuity setting to test to see if the cable is intact. And if it's sensitive enough, you could measure the resistance of it. But what you want to know is really just if you can put 5V 2A on it. Which based on it being 22 AWG, doubled up, you can without much heat or voltage drop involved.

Comment: It will work. Just do it. But you need to connect the data lines also. So if there are only 4 conductors, you can't double up the power conductors.

Comment: Passerby @mkeith you seem to be saying the opposite things.  Since there are 4 wires, can I double each of them up to make 2 conductors?  A micro USB cable has a red voltage wire, a black ground, and 2 data wires.  The data wires shouldn't do anything in this case as it terminates at the transformer.

Comment: What I am saying is use the 22AWG, but don't double it up. Just connect it wire-for-wire, one pair for data and one pair for power. Most likely the data wires are either shorted together at the transformer, or connected to proprietary voltage levels. Most likely, the device will check for that short (or proprietary voltage signal), and will not work correctly unless it sees it. This is how dedicated charging ports (DCP's) and proprietary chargers signal to USB devices that it is OK to draw up to 1.5A (or more).

Comment: I could be wrong, of course. You can cut the existing power cord and see if it has data wires. If not, then obviously I am wrong. If it does have data wires, well, they probably put them in there for a reason, and they are probably needed, but you can try running the device with them disconnected before you do any soldering.

Comment: 7amp in a 22AWG wire can be done when the cable is surrounded by air. In a bundle, ampacity is much less than that. Like less than 1amp. I wouldn't feed 1.8A in a 22AWG wire that go through my walls.

Comment: Building and electrical code in most places I know of won't care much, if at all, for low current (which it has to be for these small wires) at low voltage (< 50V).